# Utilizing Google Analytics API with Javascript - Generate Service Object

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

After reading many articles on developers.google.com, I'm still confused as the best way to go about utilizing the google analytics API with my web app.

So far I've followed [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) to obtain an access token using the correct scope, although I'm a little confused as to what to do next. My code looks like this:

```
// in my angular controller
$scope.accessToken = {};

    if (callback) {
        authService.queryToken().then(function(data) {
            $scope.accessToken = data;
            console.log($scope.accessToken);
        }, function(err) {
            $scope.accessToken = null;
        });
    }

// in my angular service
service.queryToken = function() {

        var params = {},
            queryString = location.hash.substring(1),
            regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g,
            m;
        while (m = regex.exec(queryString)) {
            params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
        }

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://' + window.location.host + '/catchtoken?' + queryString
        }).success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function() {
            deferred.reject('There was an error');
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

[This resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js) looks nice but I fail to see how I am to use the access token I've generated. My main source of confusion is the method of generating an access token only seems to mention calling the google API through HTTP, whereas the other resources mention creating a service object.

**How do I created an analytics service object with a user generated access token?**

Comment: When you say "service object", do you mean [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)?

Comment: @PhilipWalton no if you look at the recourses I posted you'll notice they talk about a 'service object'

Comment: Hmmm, I think the term "service object" in that document is a bit misleading. I believe it's just referring to the `gapi.client` global object and saying that once you've logged in and set the credentials, that object can use those credentials to make API requests without having to reauthorize. I'll post an example when I have a bit more time later.

Comment: One more question. Are you wanting your vistors to log in with their Google accounts to look at their own analytics data? Or are you wanting to get an access token to query *your* data and show it to random visitors?

Comment: @PhilipWalton look at their own analytics data, which I thought an access token was needed for that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion in the comments, it sounds like what you're really after is a way to let users sign in with their Google accounts and grant access for you to query their Google Analytics data.

If you use the [Google sign-in for web](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) flow along with the [`gapi.client.request`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequestargs)  method of the [Google APIs client library for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/), you should be able to easily authenticate your users and then freely make requests without having to worry if the access token has expired (the sign-in library automatically refreshes it behind the scenes).

Here's a sample HTML file that should get your started:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
  <script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {

      gapi.load('client', function() {
        gapi.client.request({
          path: '/analytics/v3/data/ga',
          params: {
            'ids': 'ga:XXXXX',
            'start-date': '7daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'yesterday',
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
          }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          var totalSessions = response.result.totalsForAllResults['ga:sessions'];
          console.log('Total sessions in the past week: ' + totalSessions);
        });
      });

    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that with the above code you'll have to use your own [client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingcred) in the `<meta>` tag near the top, and you'll have to replace the string `'ga:XXXXX'` with the Google Analytics view ID that you want to query. You can find your view ID using the [Google Analytics Account Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/).

Comment: are you absolutely sure it must be done this way? I've currently got a flow set up where if I'm not signed in to any google account, I'm redirected to a sign in and must grant the application access. I'm following this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you wouldn't need to include *your* view ID, you'd include the logged-in user's view ID. That means you'll probably have to present them with a view picker of sorts. At this point, you may as well consider using the [Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/), as it was built for almost exactly this purpose.

Comment: You've updated your comment ... to answer your replaced comment, the code I've shown above does the redirect to a log-in page for you. Did you try it?

Comment: I will try it and if it does that for me, I'll probably use that method. And, it looks like the Embed API is exactly what I want. I guess I was just confused why there are multiple resources for accomplishing the same task / what the differences between each approach is. Thank you!